# When covariance becomes an issue, how can I restructure my code and still be clean?

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

Suppose I have the following interfaces, `GameObject` and `Enhance`.

**GameObject**:

```
public interface GameObject {
    void prepare();
    void use();
    void cleanup();
}
```

**Enhance**:

```
public interface Enhance {
    int increase();
    int decrease();
}
```

**Goggles**:

```
public abstract class Goggles implements GameObject, Enhance {

    // The actual implementation is unnecessary to my question. 
    // Just note that the class implements GameObject and Enhance.   
}
```

**HealthPack**:

```
public abstract class HealthPack implements GameObject {

    // The actual implementation is unnecessary to my question. 
    // Just note that the class implements GameObject.
}
```

**Character**:

```
public abstract class Character {

    private final List<GameObject> inventory;
    private final List<Goggles> goggles;
    private final List<HealthPack> health;

    public Character() {
        this.inventory = new ArrayList<GameObject>();
        this.goggles = new ArrayList<Goggles>();
        this.health = new ArrayList<HealthPack>();
    }

    public void viewInventory(){
        this.drawGrid(this.inventory);
        this.drawGrid(this.goggles); // -- BOOM!
    }

    private void drawGrid(List<GameObject> items){

    }
}
```

As you probably notice, I [can't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-are-java-generics-not-implicitly-po) pass `List<Goggles> goggles;` and `List<HealthPack> health;` to the `drawGrid(List<GameObject> items)` method.

I could have a private draw method for each specific abstract type,

```
private void drawGoggles(List<Goggles> goggles)
private void drawHealthPack(List<HealthPack> healthPack)
```

but this means that for every new abstract type, I need a new draw method.

Maybe `Grid` itself is a class and an instance of grid can be given to each `GameObject` which will then pass an image and number of squares it takes up on the `Grid`. This way, it doesn't matter what specific type the `GameObject` is, the Grid class will only receive an `Image` object.

In general, what is the cleanest way to restructure the code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing

```
private void drawGrid(List<GameObject> items){
}
```

to

```
private void drawGrid(List<? extends GameObject> items){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Java very well and also don't have an opportunity to try it, but it seems to me that passing List to draw* is too specific as it implies also the method can modify the passed collection. If you passed instead `Iterable<GameObject>` or  `Iterable<? extends GameObject>` as the other answer suggests it would be more correct and easier to cast.